# How to merge XWPFDocuments to a big XWPFDocument with Java

Tags: xml, apache, apache-poi, openxml, docx

My challange is to fill up over 5000 Personrecords in a docx-Template and save each filled docx-Template in ONE docx file.

So at the end our customer will have one single docx-File to donwload.

I decided to use `Apache POI` and `XWPFDocument` - Object.

After some research i've found a way how to append multiple `XWPFDocument` to one (see the Link below). But this way is very slow.

[XWPFDocument Mail Merge](https://github.com/centic9/poi-mail-merge/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/poi/mailmerge/MailMerge.java)

Is there a faster way to merge `XWPFDocuments` ?
Or what kind of Java Library / Framework should i use instead ?

Comment: So you are trying to merge 5000 documents into a single one? Irrespective of the technology used, I don't think that's a good idea... Any chance you can fill your data directly into that single output *.docx?

Comment: I know, that is what i said to my customer but... . May be it is possibile but i need to use definitly Templates. I try to integrate this Feature in a J2EE Application. At the End it should be possible to Download this Document and print this large Document with one klick.

Comment: Why do you have to create 5000 individual files, though? Can't you just dump this data directly into your final output (while using whatever template)?

Comment: No i don't have to do that. I don't need 5000 individual files. I only need to have 5000 Pages in a single docx.

Comment: May be you can tell me how i can add my filled Template to the next Page in my XWPFDocument ? So i should be able to create a docx with a lot of pages.